# How can I install and launch Windows Server in dual boot?

Tags: linux, windows, partitioning, operating-systems

I my Server, I have a sda disk, on it I installed a Windows Server 2008, and a CentOS7.2 system.

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   209717247   104857600    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       209719296  1000214527   395247616    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       209721344   693014527   241646592    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       693016576   694040575      512000   83  Linux
/dev/sda7       694042624   752381951    29169664   8e  Linux LVM
```

I use `fdisk`, there up shows the partitions. there seems the sda1, sda2, sda3 belongs to the Windows.

Now my problem is, when I restart the Server, it will launch the CentOS7.2 system, it do not launch the Windows, there is no options. how can I launch the Windows Server?

---

My server is SuperMicro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fdisk` doesn't know or care what is stored on your disks but rather tells you that the partition is labeled as containing a "different" filesystem. If you installed both it is likely that those partitions contain Windows data but they don't have to.

To restore dual boot capabilities you will either have to manually add an entry for Windows on in your current bootloader or you will have to restore the Windows boot loader and add an entry to the Windows bootloader for your Linux system. Either way it's important to check where your current bootloader is installed because it's likely that you will overwrite it.

Comment: can you tell me how to launch the Windows SERVER?

Comment: how to  `restore the Windows boot loader`?

Comment: One option would be to launch from a bootable Windows medium and run the repair tools. One of them, I currently can't tell you which, is able to repair the boot loader. "FixMBR" and "FixBoot" should help to look for it. It might be a good idea to create a backup as both systems might end up being inaccesible.